# Count/If/Sum formula

Tags: excel, count

I am using a spreadsheet to count sold items for several teams.

Rows: Individual Seller
In column A I have the specific team the seller belongs to.
In column B I have the amount of items that the seller sold.

In a separate row at the end of the document, I am trying to calculate the total number of items being sold from a specific group.

Can anyone help me write the code needed to return the total number of items sold for each specific team?

Comment: To get a meaningful answer please read the FAQ with instructions http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and a personal favorite of mine: http://www.mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried   Furthermore stackoverflow doesnt offer you freelance programmers nor free programming...

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx

Comment: You might be interested into PivotTables.

Answer (score 0):

The image shows some sample data in A1:C13, and three different ways to sum the amounts by teams. There are many others ways. Of the three I recommend @Jerry’s suggestion of a PivotTable (E2:F6) because it is very easy to set up, very quick in operation and offers a great deal of versatility beyond merely summing amounts by team. For example if your data included dates of sales it could sort and group by week, month, year etc. The second version of it (E8:F14) shows a breakdown by Seller of the `20` total, but by the number of ‘sales’ (rows) rather than number of items sold.

[image: SO22614038 example]

The formula in D20 (copied down to D22) is:

```
=SUMIFS(B$2:B$19,A$2:A$19,A20)
```

However `SUMIFS` was not available as a standard MS Office function before Excel 2007, though `SUMIF` was, so in B20, also copied down to suit:

```
=SUMIF(A$2:A$19,A20,B$2:B$19)
```

`SUMIFS` allows more conditions than `SUMIF`, so for example can be changed in D20 to:

```
=SUMIFS(B$2:B$19,A$2:A$19,A20,C$2:C$19,"Seller1")
```

to obtain the amount of items comprising the two distinct ‘sales’ by `Seller1` as shown by `2` in the lower PivotTable.

Since you are trying to calculate the total *from a specific group* the above may be more elaborate than your immediate requirement so a version that can be placed almost anywhere in your sheet (if as the example) and even copied around, replaces a variable with a fixed condition, which I have chosen to be `teamB`:

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$19,"teamB",$B$2:B$19)
```

and provided the formula is kept out of ColumnA might be further simplified by extending it to consider entire columns:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"teamB",B:B)
```